# HashMap to implement adjacency list

Tags: java, hashmap

```
class Graph {
//Map of adjacency lists for each node

    Map<int[], LinkedList<int[]>> adj;

    public Graph(ArrayList<int[]> nodes) {
        adj = new HashMap<int[], LinkedList<int[]>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); ++i) {
            adj.put(nodes.get(i), new LinkedList<int[]>());
        }
    }

    public void addNeighbor(int [] a, int [] b) {
        adj.get(a).add(b);
    } 

    public LinkedList<int[]> getNeighbors(int a[]) {
        return adj.get(a);
    }
}


public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x= sc.nextInt();
        int y= sc.nextInt();
        int n= sc.nextInt();

        ArrayList<int []> al= new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int[] a = new int[2];
            a[0]=sc.nextInt();
            a[1]=sc.nextInt();
            al.add(i, a);
        }
        int[] s={0,100};
        int[] t={x-5,150};
        Graph g = new Graph(al);
        g.adj.put(s, new LinkedList<int[]>());
        g.adj.put(t, new LinkedList<int[]>());
        for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
            int a[]=al.get(i);
            for(int j=i;j<al.size();j++){
                int b[]=al.get(j);
                int r=100;
                int value=(int) (Math.pow(a[0]-b[0],2)+Math.pow(a[1]-b[1],2));
                if(0<=value && value <=200){
                g.addNeighbor(a, b);
                g.addNeighbor(b, a);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I have to implement an adjacency list to be used for graph for which I have used a HashMap as you can see the key value is an array which contains coordinates value (x,y) which represents a vertex in the graph.

The problem is when I want to add a new neighbour into the graph i.e add an edge between two vertices I need to add that neighbour to the respective key but that key is an array... so I want to know how do I that access key or add to the neighbours at that key. What I did is I created a new array having values equal to the key array stored in the hashmap but these two are not equal.

Please suggest a solution or any other way to store the coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store your Point in an `array`. Encapsulate the coordinates in a `Point` which you define and store this in the `HashMap`. The `Point` has members for the Coordinates of your point. Dont forget to implement `equals` and `hashCode`for your `Point`.